# Padding returns different results in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code which doesn't behave properly in Chrome. The issue is with the vertical social `div`. When I hover over the g+ icon there is a 3px high white space at the bottom.
I tried changing padding from `padding: 10px 0px 9px;` to `padding: 10px 0px 10px;` and it fixes it in Chrome, but breaks it in FireFox and IE. What exactly creates the inconsistency?

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,400italic");
  @import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css");
  body {
 padding: 60px 0px;
 background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

  .event-list {
 list-style: none;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
.event-list > li {
 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(51, 51, 51);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px 0px 20px;
}
.event-list > li > img {
 width: 100%;
}
.event-list > li > .info {
 padding-top: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}
.event-list > li > .info > .title {
 font-size: 17pt;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin: 0px;
}
.event-list > li > .info > .desc {
 font-size: 13pt;
 font-weight: 300;
 margin: 0px;
}
.event-list > li > .info > ul,
.event-list > li > .social > ul {
 display: table;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 10px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 width:100%;
}
.event-list > li > .social > ul {
 margin: 0px;
}
.event-list > li > .info > ul > li,
.event-list > li > .social > ul > li {
 display: table-cell;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
 font-size: 11pt;
 font-weight: 300;
      padding: 3px 0px;
}
  .event-list > li > .info > ul > li > a {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
 text-decoration: none;
}
  .event-list > li > .social > ul > li {
      padding: 0px;
  }
  .event-list > li > .social > ul > li > a {
      padding: 3px 0px;
}
.event-list > li > .info > ul > li:hover,
.event-list > li > .social > ul > li:hover {
 color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
 background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
.facebook a,
.twitter a,
.google-plus a {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 color: rgb(75, 110, 168) !important;
}
.twitter a {
 color: rgb(79, 213, 248) !important;
}
.google-plus a {
 color: rgb(221, 75, 57) !important;
}
.facebook:hover a {
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
 background-color: rgb(75, 110, 168) !important;
}
.twitter:hover a {
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
 background-color: rgb(79, 213, 248) !important;
}
.google-plus:hover a {
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
 background-color: rgb(221, 75, 57) !important;
}

@media (min-width: 68px) {
 .event-list > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
 .event-list > li > img  {
  display: inline-block;
 }
 .event-list > li > img {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
 }
 .event-list > li > .info {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .event-list > li > img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .info {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 40px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .info > .title,
 .event-list > li > .info > .desc {
  padding: 0px 10px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .info > ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .social {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
 }
      .event-list > li > .social > ul {
          border-left: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
      }
 .event-list > li > .social > ul > li {
  display: block;
          padding: 0px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .social > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 10px 0px 9px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .info > ul{
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <ul class="event-list">
        <li>
          <img alt="My 24th Birthday!" src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4150/5045502202_1d867c8a41_q.jpg" />
          <div class="info">
            <h2 class="title">Mouse0270's 24th Birthday!</h2>
            <p class="desc">Bar Hopping in Erie, Pa.</p>
            <ul>
              <li style="width:33%;">1 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></li>
              <li style="width:34%;">3 <span class="fa fa-question"></span></li>
              <li style="width:33%;">103 <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="social">
            <ul>
              <li class="facebook" style="width:33%;"><a href="#facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
              <li class="twitter" style="width:34%;"><a href="#twitter"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
              <li class="google-plus" style="width:33%;"><a href="#google-plus"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just specificied the height in ".event-list > li > .social > ul > li" and returned the padding in ".event-list > li > .social > ul > li > a".

The thing that was causing the issue is that the social fonts were 14px in height in chrome, but 14.67 in FF and IE so there was a 3 pixel difference across the browsers.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,400italic");
  @import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css");
  body {
 padding: 60px 0px;
 background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
}

  .event-list {
 list-style: none;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
.event-list > li {
 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(51, 51, 51);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px 0px 20px;
}
.event-list > li > img {
 width: 100%;
}
.event-list > li > .info {
 padding-top: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}
.event-list > li > .info > .title {
 font-size: 17pt;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin: 0px;
}
.event-list > li > .info > .desc {
 font-size: 13pt;
 font-weight: 300;
 margin: 0px;
}
.event-list > li > .info > ul,
.event-list > li > .social > ul {
 display: table;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 10px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 width:100%;
}
.event-list > li > .social > ul {
 margin: 0px;
}
.event-list > li > .info > ul > li,
.event-list > li > .social > ul > li {
 display: table-cell;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
 font-size: 11pt;
 font-weight: 300;
      padding: 3px 0px;
}
  .event-list > li > .info > ul > li > a {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
 text-decoration: none;
}
  .event-list > li > .social > ul > li {
      padding: 0px;
  }
  .event-list > li > .social > ul > li > a {
      padding: 3px 0px;
}
.event-list > li > .info > ul > li:hover,
.event-list > li > .social > ul > li:hover {
 color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
 background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
.facebook a,
.twitter a,
.google-plus a {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 color: rgb(75, 110, 168) !important;
}
.twitter a {
 color: rgb(79, 213, 248) !important;
}
.google-plus a {
 color: rgb(221, 75, 57) !important;
}
.facebook:hover a {
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
 background-color: rgb(75, 110, 168) !important;
}
.twitter:hover a {
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
 background-color: rgb(79, 213, 248) !important;
}
.google-plus:hover a {
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
 background-color: rgb(221, 75, 57) !important;
}

@media (min-width: 68px) {
 .event-list > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
 .event-list > li > img  {
  display: inline-block;
 }
 .event-list > li > img {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
 }
 .event-list > li > .info {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .event-list > li > img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .info {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 40px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .info > .title,
 .event-list > li > .info > .desc {
  padding: 0px 10px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .info > ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .social {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
 }
      .event-list > li > .social > ul {
          border-left: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
      }
 .event-list > li > .social > ul > li {
  display: block;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 40px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .social > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px;
 }
 .event-list > li > .info > ul{
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <ul class="event-list">
        <li>
          <img alt="My 24th Birthday!" src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4150/5045502202_1d867c8a41_q.jpg" />
          <div class="info">
            <h2 class="title">Mouse0270's 24th Birthday!</h2>
            <p class="desc">Bar Hopping in Erie, Pa.</p>
            <ul>
              <li>1 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></li>
              <li>3 <span class="fa fa-question"></span></li>
              <li>103 <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="social">
            <ul>
              <li class="facebook"><a href="#facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
              <li class="twitter"><a href="#twitter"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
              <li class="google-plus"><a href="#google-plus"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```